# Horizontally scrolling UICollectionView in a UITableview

Tags: delegates, uicollectionviewcell, uitableview

I have created a UItableView and each table cell is a UICollectionView. My view controller is the delegate and datasource for both the UITableView and UICollectionView.

The number of rows of the tableView depend on an asynchronouse request which populates an array. The number of cells inside the UICollectionView which is inside a tablecell is also determined asynchronously.

So basically, everytime I am adding to the array which drives the number of rows in the tableview - I am calling [tableView reloadData];

Which in turn triggers each cell to be reloaded. In each cell, I am setting the delegate of the UICollectionView to the controller and also calling [UICollectionView reloadData] to refresh the UICollectionView. The cells in UICollectionView are downloading images which also happens async.

My question is what is there a more elegant way to do this ?

My code is as follows

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [self.featuresTableView setDelegate:self];
    [self.featuresTableView setDataSource:self];

}
```

My viewController has is the observer of an object which is created by calling many asynchronous requests. So I have set a KVO on the object as

```
-(void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context{
if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"completedSpotSetup"]){
CustomClass * customObject = ((CustomClass*) object);
if(customObject.isValidPropertySet){
NSString *fcode = [customObject.dictionary objectForKey:@"code"];
NSMutableArray * myArray = [self.myTableRowArrayDictionary objectForKey:fcode];
    if (myArray == nil) {
                featureArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                [self.myTableRowArrayDictionary setObject:featureArray forKey:fcode];
                [self.myTableView reloadData];
            }
[myArray addObject:customObject];
}
}
```

Next in my

```
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [[[self.myTableRowArrayDictionary keyEnumerator] allObjects] count];
    }

And in the datasource for cell

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"featureCell";
        FeatureTableRowCell *cell = (FeatureTableRowCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        if (cell.tableCellCollectionView.delegate == nil ) {
            [cell.tableCellCollectionView setDelegate:self];
            [cell.tableCellCollectionView setDataSource:self];
            cell.tableCellCollectionView.tag = indexPath.row;
        }
        [cell.tableCellCollectionView reloadData];
        return cell;

    }

The controller further implements the UICollectionView datasource to determine the number of cells and data for each cell as follows

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    NSString * fcode = [self.interestsToSearch objectAtIndex:collectionView.tag];
    NSArray * myArray = [self.myTableRowArrayDictionary objectForKey:fcode];
    return [myArray count];
}






    - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        NSString * fcode = [self.interestsToSearch objectAtIndex:collectionView.tag];
            NSArray * myArray = [self.myTableRowArrayDictionary objectForKey:fcode];

        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"collectionCell";
            UICollectionViewCell *cell = (UICollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        dispatch_queue_t loaderQ = dispatch_queue_create("flickrImageLoader", NULL);
            dispatch_async(loaderQ,^{

             // Do Something

           });
        return cell;
        }
```

Doing it this way leads to VREY BAD performance and does not work that well.

What am I missing ? I think its legitimate to put a UICollectionView that scrolls horizontally inside a tableview. What is the best way to do this if I dont know upfront how many rows the UITableView will have and how many cells the UICollectionView will have when I start displaying the table. All are determined asynchronously as internet requests are resolved.

Can anyone have some patience with a long question like this and help me out ???

Comment: I don't know if it will solve your question, but did you have a look at this post already? http://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell

Comment: Thanks ! Yes I did and finally it helped me. The trick was to set the delegates at the correct place.

Comment: I have the same problem, did read the article, but did not understand what is the solution. I am setting the delegate at the willDisplayCell, but I still have to call UICollectionView.reloadData there. Is this the way to go?